# Regex: match words with underline and id

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse uniq ids, what include word with underline and some number after that symbol.
How to write correct regexp, to find all words with:

1. Lowercase conditions by specific word on first part before underline "_" symbol
2. After underline "_" symbol target string contain numbers

---

Correct matches: "word_1", "word_12312312", "word_3"

Incorrect matches: "WoRd_1", "word_", "word", "word_word", "word-123"

Comment: If it's a specific word, you can just type the word. For example: `\bword_\d+\b`. Regex is case-sensitive by default unless you use the ignore-case flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
\b[a-z]+_\d+\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJXZmT/6)

```
\b[a-z]+_\d+\b
```

Replace `[a-z]+` with `tea` to match only this word or `(teapot|pot|fork)` to match these 3 words

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJXZmT/2)

Comment: Thanks! Almost. But this regexp include all words, but need a specific "word". For example: 'tea'. 'tea_1', 'tea_123123', 'tea_3'

Comment: and in your case you need also `$` at the end check this out : https://regex101.com/r/XJXZmT/4 as you can see found two matches !

Comment: You're right but it's `\b`, not `$` because it's not necessary an end of line.

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy imagine you have some data like this :

```
tea
tea_23
tea_2132312
word_434324
words_21323
coffee_110
water_313
teapot_2321321
woRd_2213rrr
```

now as you said you wanna a `word` in lowercase mode via `_` so you can write like this :

`[a-z]+_\d+$`

for example in bash :

```
cat file.txt | grep --color -P '[a-z]+_\d+$'
```

or you can also do this for specific data, for example `tea`,`coffee`, `water`

so you can write like this

`(tea|coffee|water)_\d+$`

Comment: Don't use `\d*` but `\d+` because the `*` quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times. So `water_` or `tea_` (not followed by a number) will also match, which is incorrect. https://regex101.com/r/EzJcCd/1